# What is the symbol you'd use for Boolean results?

Tags: functions, notation, boolean-algebra

What I mean is that $\mathbb{CRZ}$ etc. are used for different classes of numbers, allowing me to do stuff like this:

$$f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$$
$$f:x\mapsto 3x$$

But say I have an expression like this:

$$g:x\mapsto x>4$$

What symbol would you use to represent a boolean result? a $\mathbb B$?

Comment: Yes, but it is not as universal as the others you mentioned. (I have seen it used for Banach spaces, for example.)

Comment: You could perhaps use $\{\top, \bot\}$.

Comment: @Regret so the result is an element of a true/false set?

Comment: @Electric: Yes, the set with true and false as elements. This is the set which you wish to represent, isn't it?

Comment: @Regret I do, but I fear $\top$ and $\bot$ could be confused with the symbols with transpose $A^{\top}$ and the orthogonal complement $W^{\bot}$ of matrices, as those are what I work with a lot

Comment: I am not aware of any standard symbol for this set, but in your texts you could define $\Bbb B=\{\text{true},\text{false}\}$ (or say the same in words), just to be clear about what $\Bbb B$ means. In the end, all that matters is that the reader can understand what you mean.

Comment: While $\top, \bot$ have some appealing symmetry, true & false or 0 & 1 have broader acceptance.

Comment: I'd go for $f:\mathbb{R}\to\{0,1\}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_domain), the most common representation is $\{0,1\}$. Alternatives include $\{\text{false},\text{true}\}$, $\{\mathrm F,\mathrm T\}$, $\{\bot,\top\}$, and $\Bbb B$.

If you wish to use either the symbol $\Bbb B$ or $\mathbf B$, you can define it yourself to prevent any ambiguity. What really matters is that the notation is readable and understandable.

Comment: I would agree that in computer science and circuit engineering just spelling it out as $\{0,1\}$ is the most common. I'm not sure about other areas, like what logicians would prefer, for example.